# Is "bug banking" occurring?

Tags: windows, attacks

Reading about the fast approaching end of support for Windows XP, I seem to come across a lot of articles which speak about bug banking. Of it being likely that towards the end of 2013 and beginning of 2014, the amount of bugs and vulnerabilities appearing for Windows XP should drop, as hackers begin to stock up on them ready to unleash them once Microsoft drops support.

But... wait a minute. It's 2014 now!

My research can't seem to dredge up any more recent articles on this problem. So I wonder, has it come true? Are there signs of bug banking going on? Is there likely to be a big zero-day assault on XP?

Comment: I disagree with the opinion-based close vote.  This question can be answered with statistics from vulnerability databases and Microsoft's own security advisories.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely an opinion-based question, as no one knows for sure, other than the well-informed in underground markets for selling such exploits.
**This does make a massive amount of sense**, and I wouldn't shrug it off.
Doubtless, there will be zero-day exploits right when support is dropped.
It's probably not as large-scale as some would think, but definitely probable.